# Scrollabel label is limited in text?

Tags: label, scrollable, kivy-language

sorry to bother you. I have recently started devolping in Kivy and i am trying to show a scrollable text file in a window. The text comes from a .txt file, and a use the id of the label to put the string obtained from the file into the text field in the Label. 
The problem i am having is that, althouugh kivy documentation firmely states that the label has no lines limit (by default), when i pass a certain number the text starts to be showed all in black as the picture i will attached. Before adding one more line to the .txt, the text can be read just fine but after adding the line the problem starts.

[After adding the line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3ywH.jpg)

[Before adding the line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUWFl.jpg)

Here is my code, **the id of the label i am having troubles with is called "documento"**. Can some please tell me if there is some error in my label configuration or something else?

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''


<RootWidget>:
    canvas.before:
    Color:
        rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
    Rectangle:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size

color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
background_color: (255, 255, 255, 1.0)
carousel: carousel

Carousel:
    on_index: root.on_index(*args)
    id: carousel
    ignore_perpendicular_swipes: True
    FloatLayout:
        id: tab1
        Label:
            id: identification    
            text: ''
            markup: True
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
            halign: 'left'
            valign: 'top'
            font_size: '18pt'
            x: 100
            y: -80
            opacity: 0

        Image:
            id: avatar
            source: 'assets/avatar.png'
            keep_ratio: True
            size_hint_x: 0.3
            x: 60
            y: -70
            opacity: 0

        Image:
            id: banner
            source: 'assets/banner.png'
            keep_ratio: True
            size_hint_x: 1
            x: 0
            y: 160
            opacity: 0

        Image:
            id: lock
            source: 'assets/lock.png'


    FloatLayout:
        id: tab2
        Label:
            id: asunto    
            text: 'Asunto: [b] Expdte. 234/98634987/54[/b]'
            markup: True
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
            halign: 'left'
            valign: 'top'
            font_size: '18pt'
            x: 40
            y: 170
            opacity: 0

        Image:
            id: votacion
            size_hint_x: 0.2
            x: 20
            y: 80
            opacity: 1

        Label:
            id: voto_text    
            text: '[b]VOTO POSITIVO[/b]'
            markup: True
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
            halign: 'left'
            valign: 'top'
            font_size: '40pt'
            y: 90
            x: 40
            opacity: 1

        Image:
            id: biometric_icon
            source: 'assets/biometric.png'
            keep_ratio: False
            size_hint_x: 0.2
            y: -90
            x: 320
            opacity: 1

        Label:
            id: confirm_label    
            text: 'CONFIRMACI\xc3\x93N BIOM\xc3\x89TRICA'
            markup: True
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'top'
            font_size: '10pt'
            y: -190
            x: 00
            opacity: 1

    FloatLayout:
        id: tab3
        ScrollView:
            on_scroll_start: print("arranque")
            on_scroll_move: print("me muevo")
            on_scroll_stop: print("pare")
            Label:
                id: documento
                text_size:700, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)

    Label:
        id: debugger
        text: ''
        color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
        halign: 'left'
        valign: 'top'
        width: 200



 ''')
```

Answer (score 0):

I continue my search for a solution to this problem only to discover there was a limitation in my gpu for rendering the text, so the problem was that. So to sum-up and help everyone who is having the same problem, the limitation is not from kivy but from the gpu